# Why does \insertauthor lead to an error inside \ifthenelse statement?

Tags: beamer, author, ifthenelse

Using `\insertauthor` in `\ifthenelse` statement throws an error (no error if it is used elsewhere in the document). `\inserttitle` or `\insertdate` works fine. Why do I get an error when I use `\insertauthor` as below? You can see that I am trying to check if author information is provided.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ifthen}

%\title{Title goes here}
\author{me}

\begin{document}

\ifthenelse{\equal{\insertauthor}{}}{empty}{not empty}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `\insertauthor` macro does more than just inserting the author, so you run into a problem with exandability.

Instead you can check if `\beamer@shortauthor` or `\beamer@andstripped` is empty or not (the result will be different for the case `\author[]{me}`, not sure which behaviour you would like).

I also included a second approach which is used in beamer to test e.g. in footlines if certain information is available

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\author{me}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fooooo}{\ifthenelse{\equal{\beamer@shortauthor}{}}{empty}{not empty}}

\newcommand{\foo}{\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{\beamer@shortauthor}{empty}{not empty}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\fooooo

\foo
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```