# How can I access \institute content with \ifthenelse in beamer?

Tags: beamer, ifthenelse

I try to check if \institute is empty in a beamer document. This fails.

I found the solution for \author already here:
[Why does \insertauthor lead to an error inside \ifthenelse statement?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/679478/why-does-insertauthor-lead-to-an-error-inside-ifthenelse-statement)

You can access \beamer@shortauthor to check if author is empty.

What is the solution for \institute?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ifthen}

%\title{Title goes here}
\institute{me}

\begin{document}
    
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\insertinstitute}{}}{empty}{not empty}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get some inspiration from the [inmargin inner theme](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/base/themes/inner/beamerinnerthemeinmargin.sty), which also tests for an empty institute and uses a `\ifx...\else...\fi` construct for this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\institute{me}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\testinst}{%
 \ifx\insertinstitute\@empty
  empty
 \else
  not empty
 \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\testinst
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. This does work in a single file. However, the `\makeatletter` seems to break the build when put into beamerinnertheme.sty.

Comment: @mrCarnivore You don't need the `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` inside a sty file. @ will automatically be a letter there.

Comment: Thanks for that hint. It turned out to be another problem. The error messages of LaTeX are really not helpful at all when debugging...

Comment: @mrCarnivore The error messages are very helpful if you actually show them to people and not just say "it does not work"

Comment: I think in this case you would also need the context. The error message was "Argument of \@xdblarg has an extra }" in one line of the main document. The problem was I used \date instead of \insertdate inside one function of the .sty...